# Как раз(,) раз в год можно

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

Answer (score 3):

Здесь запятая не нужна: *как раз* — частица. Но грамотнее будет написать "Как раз можно раз в год", это облегчит понимание смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Тавтология в вашем высказывании, требуется корректировка текста.

**Именно раз в год можно. Или лучше: можно именно раз в год.** Запятой устойчивое  сочетание не выделяется, выполняет функцию частицы.

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/как_раз](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)

**КАК РАЗ,** Употр. при выделении, подчеркивании последующего слова; **именно** ◆ Чагатаев любил размышлять о том, что раньше не удалось сделать людям, потому что **как раз это самое** ему необходимо было исполнить. А. П. Платонов, «Джан», 1933–1935 г. ◆ Чёрт возьми, это к**ак раз то, что мне нужно**! Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий, «Жук в муравейнике», 1979 г.